# Scaling in bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, scaling, horizontal-scaling

`cf scale myApp –i 5` is for horizontal scaling,
`cf scale myApp -k 512M` is for vertical scaling.

What happens when we use the above horizontal and vertical scaling commands? Do they increase the number of instances by adding 5 and Disk Size by adding 512M, or will the overall application instances be 5 and overall disk size be 512M?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-i, -k, and -m all take the new absolute values not an increment.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/cf-scale.html

> Use cf scale APP -i INSTANCES to horizontally scale your application.
>   Cloud Foundry **will increase or decrease the number of instances of
>   your application to match INSTANCES.**